# How to generate documentation for ratpack application?

Tags: ratpack

While I integrating swagger2 to my rat pack application, It's not generating rest API documentation for rat pack handlers.Is it possible to generate REST API documentation with swagger2 is there any other tool to generate documentation for rat pack application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current way to do this as Ratpack handlers are dynamic at run-time. There has been talk of this, but nothing further. We use Swagger2 with Ratpack, but generated manually. We also embed `swagger-ui` into the app.